# Can anyone help explain why this Python code outputs: [0]

Tags: python

```
myli = range(-2,2)
m = list(filter(lambda x: True if abs(x) < 1 else False, myli))
print(m)
```

Comment: What would you expect the code to output?

Comment: Which parts do you and do you not understand?

Comment: Do you understand what `abs()` does?

Comment: I thought it would iterate 4 times between (-2, 1) and return a list of either True or False depending on whether the abs(x) is < 1 or not.

Comment: `map` would do something like that, mapping numbers to booleans. `filter` on the other hand retains the numbers that match and removes the ones that don't.

Comment: `lambda x: abs(x) < 1` would suffice; no need to replace the `bool` that the comparison evaluates to with explicit `bool` values.

Answer (score 6):

It is [0], because the only number between -2 and 1 whose absolute value is smaller than 1 is 0, since

```
-2 -> abs(-2) = 2   > 1   # False
-1 -> abs(-1) = 1  == 1   # False
 0 -> abs(0)  = 0   < 1   # True
 1 -> abs(1)  = 1  == 1   # False
```

And `filter` function returns a *sublist* of the iterable given, composed only of elements that satisfy the given condition.